# Newly elected moderator lost his diamond?

Tags: bug, election, flair, caching

Well, not really - just the flair image.

I am talking about [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679) who [was elected several hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3) and does have the diamond in the profile, however:

[image: screenshot]

Live flair:

[image]

Knowing the system by now I assume it's because the flair data is cached and as Brad [didn't perform any real activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson?tab=activity) aka reputation event since being elected, the flair data has not been updated.

Dunno what it means behind the scenes, but maybe changing one's status to moderator should also trigger reputation event just to make sure all the caches are reloaded?

Comment: Reading this title gave me the hiccups. Well played sir, well played.

Comment: @Tim thanks (I guess :)) but can you confirm it's not server cache of some sort?

Comment: I accuse caching on the server with the lead piping.

Answer (score 4):

It looks your computer still has the old version of the flair image cached. It shows the diamond on his flair image fine for me, and has shown it fine since I first checked the about page shortly after the announcement of the new moderators.

[image: It's showing for me.]

Comment: True, hard refresh "solved" it but still - why Brad and not the other two? Still smells of server cache as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

As addon to Animuson answer,

I can see that all three new elected moderators have diamonds.

May be check on the other browsers.

Do a forceful refresh <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and see.

Comment: That's what I did and it indeed brought the diamond back, thanks.